# Youtube HTML5 video embed not working in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, youtube

I am using following code to embed a Youtube video with HTML5 player. It is working fine in Chrome and IE but failing in Firefox.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mwG7z_aowKw?html5=1" ></iframe>
```

Version of Firefox is 26.0

Is there any error in the iframe code? 
Is there any work-around possible?

update - Working in safe mode with addons disabled.
But Problem still persist when disabled all addons in normal mode.
How to debug this problem?

Comment: yes it does for me, its showing all docks, cranes etc.

Comment: what's your firefox's version?

Comment: the version you mentioned

Comment: update - Working in safe mode with addons disabled.
But Problem still persist when disabled all addons in normal mode.
How to debug this problem?

Comment: May be some of your addon is causing that issue

Comment: But they are all off. how to figure it out?

Comment: Switch on one by one and check

Comment: Already switched them all off. but problem still persist :(

Comment: do you see error occurred black screen on the video?

Comment: Not blank screen. It's skipping off to the end of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me - FF 27. There is no error in iframe I would say there is something wrong with yours FF.

Comment: update - Working in safe mode with addons disabled.
But Problem still persist when disabled all addons in normal mode.
How to debug this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a problem with a Youtube video not running on my Wordpress site, www.marcoislandscene.tv. It works fine on Chrome and IE.

YouTube generated the following code:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/afOCUx-xnsw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This code would display the preview but the video wouldn't run. I removed "-nocookie" from the code and it runs fine on FF, IE and Chrome.